# iPhone Calender Getting Event Correct

Tags: iphone

I used to live in Arizona.  I now live in Virginia.
When entering an event on the iPhone, I enter the time, say 9:00 AM.  My iPhone calender is sync'd with the Outlook calender on my PC.  When the alert for the event entered on the iPhone, appears, it is two hours early.  9:00 AM is now 7:00 AM. This happens on both calenders.

The time difference between VA & AZ is two hours.  Is this the cause of the problem?
When I enter an event on the Outlook calender, when the alert arrives, the time is correct on both devices.

The time on the iPhone is set to New York, the default.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that inside Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars the timezone for the calendar is correct. It may still be on your old Arizona timezone.

Comment: I looked in the settings you suggested, & found the time zone override.  It was set to Washington, DC, which I thought would be correct.  I have turned that off.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: To my knowledge, Washington, DC and New York are indeed in the same timezone, which is confusing.  Let's see what happens to new events after you turned off that setting (existing events may not change without recreating them).